# What is ItemEvents_10? My 3rd party add-in crash log shows it

Tags: windows, com, outlook-addin

I might be on the wrong site, I think I am suppose to be at SuperUser, but I thought I ask here first. Recently, my company's 3rd party add-in for Outlook started to crash often and event viewer kept showing this ItemEvents_10 is causing our add-in to crash. What is ItemEvents_10?

Based on what I research on, ItemEvents_10 is a COM class that is not supposed to be used in our code. But it shows little or insufficient information for me to fully understand what it does. So I decided to take it here to ask if anyone is familiar with it. I hope anyone with the knowledge would be kind to share. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [ItemEvents_10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_methods.aspx) interface provides a set of events available in the Outlook object model. Looks like an exception was thrown in one of event handlers.

Comment: I yes you are right, it is an exception. When I looked up the Microsoft site, MSDN, I did read a few info about this but still unsure what is causing these exceptions. The odd issue is that these exceptions didn't appear until at least a few months ago. My company software has been in the market since the beginning. And I am unsure if it has to do with the recent Windows Update. What puzzles me the most is this line I took from the MSDN site: *This interface is not intended to be used in your code.*

Comment: I don't see your code and what interfaces and classes are used.

Comment: i am sorry, I cannot display my code due to confidentiality issue. I can only ask about this to learn more about ItemEvents_10. I hope you can understand